# How can I set a Variable at my Microservice, which is selected from Angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot

i have a problem. How can I set a Variable at my Microservice , which is selected from Angular? I have this Code:

Service:

```
private httpOptions = {headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})};
private dateUrl = '//localhost:8085/dates';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}

setDate(date: Dates) {
  return this.http.post(this.dateUrl, date, this.httpOptions);
}
```

And Controller:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController

public class DateController {

    @Autowired
    private DateService dateService;

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET ,value = "/dates")
    public Dates newDate(@RequestBody Dates dates) {
        dateService.setDate(dates);
        return this.dateService.getDate();
    } 
}
```

Does anyone has a resolution or a hint?

Edit: These are the classes for understanding

Service Class

```
@Service
    public class DateService {
    private Dates date;
    private Date from;
private Date to;

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    date= new Dates(from,to);
}

public Dates getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Dates date) {
    this.date = date;
}
}
```

Class Date:

```
public class Dates {
    private Date from;
    private Date to;

public Dates(Date from, Date to) {
    this.from = from;
    this.to = to;
}

public Date getFrom() {
    return from;
}

public void setFrom(Date from) {
    this.from = from;
}

public Date getTo() {
    return to;
}

public void setTo(Date to) {
    this.to = to;
}
}
```

Here is the ComponentClass:

```
export class DateComponent implements OnInit {
  dateRange = new Dates;

  constructor(private dateService: DateService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.setDate();
  }

  setDate(): void {
    this.dateService.setDate(this.dateRange);
  }


}
```

I have tried everything...please help me guys

Comment: Send value using http request and store it somewhere on the backend?

Comment: But anywa, what is wrong with the code you provided? Looks fine.

Comment: if you getting any error please share it

Comment: I dont get any error but it will not set the value. the Date is everytime null. Date is defined by the variable from which is a Date and to which is a date too

Comment: Please show the angular conponent code, and where you see null date?

Comment: @hamilton.lima edited

Comment: and null if i enter to localhost:8085/dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setDate method from angular returns `Observable` from the call of  `http.post`. The `Observable` doesn't contain the result itself so in order to use it you need to subscribe to the result, like this

```
this.dateService.setDate(this.dateRange).subscribe( finalResult => {
  this.dateRange = finalResult;
});
```

Comment: Edit: Error:Type definition error: [simple type, class info.flight.date.Dates]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of info.flight.date.Dates (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]"

Comment: Never mind got the solution just a empty constructor in date haha... Thank you so much for your Help!